# How to display Table of following data Table in HTML of Angular 7 Application obtained through through .TS call from API

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, observers

In Angular 7 application, I was trying to get the tabular data from API call and assign the same to the HTML elements. added the following code here.
I was able to log the data in the inner parenthesis of call code but the data was not available out of it.
I am not able to assign it to any HTML element.

Typescript class:

```
export class IBiodatas{
    CompanyId:number;
    EmpCode: string;
    ImageURL: string;
    Name: string;
    UserId : number;
}
```

Typescript service call :

```
getDetail(userName):Observable<IBiodatas[]>{
  return this.http.get<IBiodatas[]>(this.API_URL + userName,this.httpOptions).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('getDetail',[]))
  )
}
```

Typescript component code :

```
heroes: IBiodatas[];

getDetail(): void {
    this.biodataService.getDetail('?userName=Santosh')
      .subscribe(      
        data=> {
          this.heroes = Array.of(data.data.Table[0]);//Error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IBiodatas[]'.
          console.log('456456',this.heroes);
        },
      );
  }
```

Received data from API :

```
{
"APIExecutionTime":"0 sec(s) to execute the function",
"data":{
    "Table":[{
    "UserId":654,
    "ImageURL":"654.png",
    "Name":"Santosh Pal",
    "CompanyId":78,"EmpCode":"987"
    }]},
"httpStatusCode":200,
"msg":"OK",
"IsValid":true
}
how to get data.Table[0] and assign to class property
```

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(30,41): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IBiodatas[]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getDetail(){

```
this.biodataService.getDetail('?userName=Santosh').subscribe
(data =>{
    this.heroes1 = Array.of(data)
    this.heroes = Array.of(this.heroes1[0].data.Table[0]);
});
```

}

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>UserId</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of data.Table">
      <td>{{data.UserId}}</td>
      <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

`this.data = JSON.stringify(res);` instead of use just `this.data = res.data.table`

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>UserId</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
      <td>{{d.UserId}}</td>
      <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```